# IOS option in Target platform section is grey and not clickable

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I tried to install Xamarin Automatically on my mac. But the download failed again and again. SO I had to download all files manually then install it. I downloaded Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Ios with others and installed it. But The Ios part is not working..

Do I need to install Xcode before doing it?

I tried to auto update from xamarin ide too. But it also failed at 60%.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin unified installer will download and install everything you need. You can find it [here](https://www.xamarin.com/download).

For iOS, you will need a Mac with all the native development tools installed, this includes Xcode which can be found on the App Store. Detailed instructions about setting up your Mac are available in the documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/).